# Command line error D8036 - not allowed with multiple source files with node-gyp and VS2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, node-gyp

I am using node-gyp to build a Cpp project. In my binding.gyp file I under sources I have something like this:

```
"sources": [
"./somepath/*.cpp"
]
```

This used to work without issue with VS2019 but with VS2022 I am getting the error in the title. If I type the file names individually it works but under one directory there are too many files and I can't list them all one by one. Is there a known solution for this?

Comment: Please include the full error message as it will say which command line option is not allowed when compiling multiple source files - see - [Command-Line Error D8036](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/command-line-error-d8036?view=msvc-170).